# Parsing xml using dataframe

Tags: xml, apache-spark, dataframe

Using spark dataframe I want to parse an xml file. Below is my xml file and code.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<paml version="2.0" xmlns="paml20.xsd">
  <kmData type="partial">
    <header>
      <log dateTime="2016-11-10T07:01:37" action="created">partial used</log>
    </header>
    <Object class="SSC" version="0.3" dName="p2345" id="600">
    <list name="sscOptions">
        <p>0</p>
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
        <p>4</p>
      </list>
    <p name="AAA">2</p>
      <p name="BBB">3</p>
      <p name="CCC">NNN</p>
      <p name="DDD">26</p>
      <p name="EEE">30</p>
      <p name="FFF">30</p>
      <p name="GGG">80</p>
      <p name="HHH">20</p>
      <p name="III">100</p>
      </Object>
    <Object class="PLUS2" version="0.5" dName="p2346" id="700">
      <p name="AAA">5</p>
      <p name="BBB">1</p>
      <p name="CCC">0</p>
      <p name="DDD">0</p>
      <p name="EEE">0</p>
      <p name="FFF">0</p>
      <list name="PLUS2Out">
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
        <p>0</p>
      </list>
      <p name="GGG">8</p>
      </Object>
   </kmData>
 </paml>
```

I tried with below code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType, DoubleType}

object cmdataframeprocessing {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setAppName("Parse XML Data").setMaster("local[*]"))
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("AAA", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("BBB", StringType, nullable = true),
    StructField("CCC", StringType, nullable = true)))
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.read
    .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
    .option("rowTag", "Object")
    .schema(customSchema)
    .load("/home/tcs/xmldata.xml")
    print("xml file read done")
    val Data1 = df.filter("class = 'SSC'")
    val D1store=Data1.select("AAA","BBB").show()
  }
}
```

With this code am getting error:

```
xml file read doneException in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'class' in the given input column AAA,BBB,CCC;
```

Here with the normal xml tags I can able to read the data.
But the tag contain **P name** p name="AAA" I am getting this issue.
Please help me how can I extract the values.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to read `value` of `<p>` where its `name` is either `AAA` or `BBB`

In such case you can do something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml").option("rowTag", "Object").load("D:/input.xml")
df.printSchema
```

This gives us the following:

```
root
 |-- _class: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _dName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- _version: double (nullable = true)
 |-- list: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- p: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- p: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _VALUE: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _name: string (nullable = true)
```

Then we will parse based on the condition like below:

```
val Data1 = df.filter(df("_class") === "SSC")
val result = Data1.select(explode(Data1("p")).as("p")).select("p.*")
result.where(result("_name") === "AAA" || result("_name") === "BBB").show()
```

this gives the following output:

```
+------+-----+
|_VALUE|_name|
+------+-----+
|     2|  AAA|
|     3|  BBB|
+------+-----+
```

### UPDATE:

```
result.select("_VALUE").where(result("_name") === "AAA" || result("_name") === "BBB").show()

+------+
|_VALUE|
+------+
|     2|
|     3|
+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Prasad.Here I want the result in the form of 2,3 . and I don't want _name(AAA,BBB) to be printed.Please tell me how can I do that .

Comment: @Khumar then you need to select only _VALUE from your dataframe. Check the updated answer